# Why asyncio's run_in_executor gives so little parallelization when making HTTP requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've written a benchmark utility that batch queries a REST endpoint. It does it in three ways:

1. sequentially, using the requests library,
2. concurrently, using the requests library, but wrapping each request with `loop.run_in_executor()`,
3. concurrently, using the aiohttp library.

Below are the results with different batch sizes:

batch_size=16

```
       concur_times  seq_times  concur_aiohttp_times
count     50.000000  50.000000             50.000000
mean       0.123786   0.235883              0.087843
std        0.009733   0.018039              0.029977
min        0.108682   0.210515              0.071560
25%        0.118666   0.222436              0.075565
50%        0.121978   0.231876              0.080050
75%        0.125740   0.242939              0.086345
max        0.169194   0.283809              0.267874
```

batch_size=4

```
       concur_times  seq_times  concur_aiohttp_times
count     50.000000  50.000000             50.000000
mean       0.080764   0.091276              0.052807
std        0.008342   0.016509              0.033814
min        0.069541   0.078517              0.041993
25%        0.076142   0.082242              0.044563
50%        0.079046   0.085540              0.045735
75%        0.081645   0.092659              0.049428
max        0.111622   0.170785              0.281397
```

As the results show, the aiohttp routine is consistently more parallel by a wide margin. What's more, with a small batch size (4), the 2nd approach of using `loop.run_in_executor` ("concur_times" column) achieves only a speed up of 1/9 v. the sequential method.

Why is that? Is my code at fault? I'm including it below.

I've tried swapping out the network IO for `sleep` and `asyncio.sleep` and that produced expected results of methods 2 and 3 being equally fast and method 1 being batch_size times slower.

Code:

```
import asyncio
import requests
from cytoolz.curried import *
import pandas as pd
from timeit import default_timer as now

url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'

def dl_todo_with_requests(session, n):
        response = session.get(url + str(n))
        assert(response.status_code == 200)
        text = response.text
        return text

dl_todo_with_requests = curry(dl_todo_with_requests)

def seq_dl(todos_to_get):
        with requests.Session() as session:
                todos = pipe(
                        todos_to_get,
                        map( dl_todo_with_requests(session) ),
                        list )
                return todos

get_todos_from_futures = lambda futures: \
        pipe( futures,
                map( lambda fut: fut.result() ),
                list
            )

async def concur_dl(todos_to_get):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        with requests.Session() as session:
                completed_futures, _pending = await \
                        pipe(
                        todos_to_get,
                        map( lambda n:
                                loop.run_in_executor(
                                None,
                                lambda: dl_todo_with_requests(session, n)
                                )),
                        list,
                        asyncio.wait
                        );
                todos = get_todos_from_futures(completed_futures)
                return todos

import aiohttp
async def concur_dl_aiohttp(todos_to_get):
        async def dl(session, todo):
                async with session.get(url + str(todo)) as resp:
                        assert(resp.status == 200)
                        return resp.text()
        dl = curry(dl)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                unexecuted = pipe(
                        todos_to_get,
                        map( dl(session) ),
                        list )
                completed_futures, _pending = await asyncio.wait(unexecuted)
                todos = get_todos_from_futures(completed_futures)
                return todos


def check_todos_received(todos):
        assert(len(todos) == len(todos_to_get))
        todo_has_content = lambda todo: len(todo) > len('{}')
        assert(all(map(todo_has_content, todos)))
        return True

def measure_it(f):
        start = now();
        f()
        elapsed = now() - start
        return elapsed

inspect = lambda f, it: map(do(f), it)
inspect = curry(inspect)

def bench(n_iters=50,batch_size=4):
        todos_to_get = range(1,batch_size+1)
        seq_dl(todos_to_get)
        # heat caches, if any
        measure_seq = lambda: pipe(
                        seq_dl(todos_to_get),
                        inspect(check_todos_received) )
        measure_concur = lambda: pipe(
                        asyncio.run(concur_dl(todos_to_get)),
                        inspect(check_todos_received) )
        measure_concur_aiohttp = lambda: pipe(
                        asyncio.run(concur_dl_aiohttp(todos_to_get)),
                        inspect(check_todos_received) )
        do_the_bench = lambda dl_f, title: \
               pipe( range(n_iters),
                       inspect(
                               lambda n: \
                               print("doing %s/%s %s batch download" \
                                       % (n+1,n_iters,title))),
                        map(lambda _: measure_it(dl_f)),
                        list )
        concur_times = do_the_bench(measure_concur,'concurrent')
        concur_aiohttp_times = do_the_bench(measure_concur_aiohttp,'concurrent_aiohttp')
        seq_times = do_the_bench(measure_seq,'sequential')
        return dict(
                concur_times=concur_times,
                seq_times=seq_times,
                concur_aiohttp_times=concur_aiohttp_times)
```

The benchmark is run like this: `bench(n_iters=50,batch_size=4)`. Then pass the output through `lambda output: pandas.DataFrame(output).describe()` to produce the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default executor for asyncio's `run_in_executor` is [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), which uses Python threads. So it is also affected by the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991710/is-concurrent-futures-a-medicine-of-the-gil) thread.

In your case only one thread with asynchronous job runs at a time, resulting aiohttp to show better performance.